# How do I renormalize these probability distributions?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, beta-function

So I have two random variables, $X_1$ and $X_2$, both uniformly distributed on $[0, 1]$.

If $Y = (X_1 + X_2) / 2$, it will also be distributed between 0 and 1, but it won't be uniformly distributed any more. How do I "renormalize" it? I want a $Y_b = f(Y)$ to be also uniformly distributed on $[0, 1]$.

More generally, I'd like a generalized version of $f$, that I can also use for the weighted average of $n$ variables.

I would know how to do this for normally-distributed variables (the variance of the sum is the sum of the variances, so I can adjust), but not for a uniform variance...

Any pointers? (should I ask this on stats.stackexchange instead?)

Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't really work that way. If the distribution you have isn't uniform, you can't really preserve it's distribution while 'renormalizing' to uniform.

Comment: I can imagine a way using characteristic functions and deconvolution with some assumptions. Are you familiar with the characteristic function and how it behaves under addition / averaging?

Also, is your final application data driven? Are you going to sample from something like $Y$ and try to determine the mean and variance of the $X$ variables? If so, that's a totally different problem in parameter estimation.

Comment: jameselmore: I agree; "renormalize" may not be the right term (hence the scare quotes), do you have a better one? "re-uniformify" ? I don't need to preserve the distribution.

Comment: rajb245: I'm not sure what you're getting at with characteristic functions. My final application isn't data driven; I'm building a generative system with random parameters and it would be more convenient if all my variables had the same distributions. Maybe it would be simpler if I just switched everything to normal distributions...

Answer (score 1):

I think the function you want is the CDF, which is the integral of the PDF.

The PDF of $Y=(X_1+X_2)/2$ is $2-4|x-1/2|$.  To return that to uniform, you could do 
$$f(y)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}2y^2 &(y<1/2)\\1-2(1-y)^2&(y>1/2)\end{array}\right.$$
For (X_1+X_2+X_3)/3, I think the PDF is made of three different quadratics, and $f$ is made of three different cubics.  From memory, it is 
$$f_3(y)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}Ay^3&(y<1/3)\\Ay^3+B(y-1/3)^3&(1/3<y<2/3)\\Ay^3+B(y-1/3)^3+C(y-2/3)^3&(2/3<y<1)\end{array}\right.$$
where $A,B$ and $C$ are chosen so that $f_3(1)=1,f'_3(1)=0,f''_3(1)=0$
$A,B,C$ are in the ratio $1,-3,3$, where $1,3,3$ comes from Pascal's Triangle and the signs alternate.
I think $A=3^2/2!$, so:
for $f_4$, $A=4^3/3!$ and $A:B:C:D=1:-4:6:-4$
and for $f_5$, $A=5^4/4!$ and $A:B:C:D:E=1:-5:10:-10:5$

Comment: Thanks for that function! Is there a way to generalize it, to either an average of n, or a weighted sum, or even worse, a weighted average? I could probably work it out for a given n, but if I had a nice theory that made that easier... (I have a case where n=9, working that out by hand is going to be tedious...)